# Yii динамические поля формы

Tags: php, yii

С помощью вот этого способа:

```
<div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'embed'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'embed', array('rows'=>4, 'cols'=>73)); ?>
            <script>
            var count = 0;

        function addField()
        {
            $("#container").append('<div id="ttt' + (++count) + '"><span>Плеер ' + count + '</span><br /><textarea rows="4" cols="73" name="Match[embed][' + count + ']" id="Match_embed"></textarea><input onclick="delField(' + count + '); return false;" type="button" value="Удалить" /><div>');
        }
        function delField(counter)
        {
            $("#ttt" + counter).remove();
        }
        </script>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <?php echo CHtml::Button('Добавить', array('onclick'=>'addField(); return false;')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'embed'); ?>
    </div>
```

добавил поля. 
Сохранить получилось. Ну а как теперь их обновить при вызове actionUpdate????

Answer (score 2):

При отправлении этой формы на сервер приходит массив в глобальной переменной _POST под ключом, соответствующем названию вашей модели (я так понял, это Match). Соответственно ваши добавленные поля придут как массив, к которому можно обратиться вот так:

```
$_POST['Match']['embed']
```

или вот так:

```
if (($data = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Match', false)) != false)
   $fields = $data['embed'];
```

В этом массиве под ключами, которые задавались в яваскрипте с помощью переменной count, вы и найдете введенные данные. Если ключи не интересуют, то можно просто использовать массив с помощью foreach.
Как именно после этого их обрабатывать и сохранять - вопрос к той логике, которую вы задумали на сервере.

Если я неправильно понял и под actionUpdate подразумевается заполнение формы - то надо вытянуть сохраненные данные, и с помощью опять же foreach создать для каждого из них textarea.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $entry)
    CHtml::textArea('Match[embed]['.$key.']', $entry);
```

Comment: Спасиба)))